# LWUIT TextArea text formatting how to?

Tags: java-me, format, lwuit

> I work on a LWUIT project  that aims to computerize  an Arabic book . That means each page of the
>
> mentioned  book accessed by  a specific  button

returns

> To do that I created a form , array of  buttons, and a textarea.
>
> The setText( ) method  of  textarea  widget is used to involve each page of the book 
>   How?
>
> When  a button pressed
>
> the setText( ) changes  it's  string according to the content of the
>
> required   page

returns

> At the end of the project  a  problem of  formatting  faces me .
>
> The book page's  contents (Strings ) are unformatted.

returns

> to solve the problem I tried   a LWUIT HtmlComponent instead of textArea in  order to format using
>
> html tags  , but  it takes   much of  memory
>
> (at least it cost more than 700 kb for an application).
>
> So I wouldn't be able include all the pages of the book by this way.

returns

This my first  trial

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

 import com.sun.lwuit.events.*;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.*;


import com.sun.lwuit.*;


public class Arabic_Lang extends MIDlet {

    public void startApp()
    {
 com.sun.lwuit.Display.init(this);

  final  com.sun.lwuit.Form main_form = new com.sun.lwuit.Form();

   final  com.sun.lwuit.Form  f = new com.sun.lwuit.Form();


   final com.sun.lwuit.TextArea txt1 = new com.sun.lwuit.TextArea();

   f.addComponent(txt1);

  final   com.sun.lwuit.Button l[]= new  com.sun.lwuit.Button [3];

  final com.sun.lwuit.Button inter = new com.sun.lwuit.Button("inter");


   final  com.sun.lwuit.Form jjj8 = new com.sun.lwuit.Form();

   jjj8.setTitle( "اللغة العربية");

  jjj8.getStyle().setBgColor(0x006699);

  jjj8.setScrollableX(true);

   int i;


   for(i=0;i<3;i++)

  {

    l[i] =new com.sun.lwuit.Button();


  l[i].getStyle().setBgColor(0xFFF66);

 main_form.addComponent(l[i]);

 main_form.setScrollable (true);

 main_form.setScrollableX(false);

        }
       l[0].setText("");

l[0].getStyle().setBgColor(0xffff00);


l[0].setText("arabic");

l[1].setText("arabic");

  l[0].addActionListener(new  ActionListener(){

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

  txt1.setText(" \u0628 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0644\u063A\u062A");

 }

});

  l[1].addActionListener(new  ActionListener(){

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {


txt1.setText(" \u0628 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0644\u063A\u062A");

f.show();

}
});


jjj8.addComponent(inter);

inter.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

  main_form.show();

  }
}
 );

jjj8.show();

    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }
}
```

returns

And  this is my trial to use htmlComponent

returns

```
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.*;


import javax.microedition.midlet.*;


public class HelloLWUITMidlet3 extends MIDlet

{

  public void startApp()
  {
   com.sun.lwuit.Display.init(this);

  final com.sun.lwuit.Form form = new com.sun.lwuit.Form("");

  final com.sun.lwuit.html.HTMLComponent htmlC = new com.sun.lwuit.html.HTMLComponent( );


   htmlC.setRTL(true);

   htmlC.setBodyText("هذه لغة عربية","UTF-8" );

    form.addComponent(htmlC);


    BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();

    form.setScrollable(true);


    form.show( );

   }

  public void pauseApp() 
  {

  }

 public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {


 }


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the pages of the book as HTML files in your src dir (in the jar root) and load them directly into the HTMLComponent as is shown in the LWUITDemo.